# Show page footer only on 1st page of Access report

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access report and I'm able to only show the page footer on the 1st page by putting the below code in the OnPrint event for the page footer, but when I print it to PDF it doesn't show the footer at all. I've tried adding the code to the OnFormat event, but that doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

```
Private Sub PageFooterSection_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
    Me.PageFooterSection.Visible = Me.[Page] = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not finding any method that preserves this conditional footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access 2016 there is a specific solution.  I'm not sure about other Access versions.  Go to the report properties.  under the format properties you will find both Report Header and Report Footer.  Both should be set by default to "all pages". Set Report Footer to "Not with Rpt Hdr"

*it looks like they didn't update or adjust for their old enum*

Note: All other approaches I tried still set aside blank space for the footer even if you couldn't see it.  I tried many combination of setting controls and the PageFooterSection to invisible or height 0.
original answer:

Flip the problem around. Show the text if the page is 1.  Controls in the footer have access to the [page] object  which gives you the page number.  For instance, put a textbox in the page footer and set the textbox control source to something like:

```
=IIf([Page]=1,"Show this only on page 1","")
```

In my test the footer only showed on the first page in print preview and pdf.

Comment: I have a combination of labels and text boxes in my footer and using your logic I could hide all of those from any page after page 1, but the other issue I run into is that my detail items do not expand on pages after page 1. Even though the footer is not visible it treats the report as if there is still a footer and doesn't expand the detail lines. Is there a way around this? @mazoula

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show page footer only on page 1 and you prefer minimalistic approach:

```
Private Sub PageFooterSection_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    PageFooterSection.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Page()
    PageFooterSection.Visible = False
End Sub
```

If you want to make it more flexible, and be able to control pages individually:

```
Private Sub PageFooterSection_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    PageFooterSection.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Page()
Select Case Page
Case 0, 2, 4 'shows footer only on pages 1,3,5
    PageFooterSection.Visible = True
Case Else
    PageFooterSection.Visible = False
End Select
End Sub
```